# jQuery 2nd click to call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have the following HTML

```
<a onclick="hi('#i_15', 'second_img.jpg'); return false;" href="http://google.com">
<img id="i_15" src="first_img.jpg" />
</a>
```

So, I don't want it to follow to google.com when it's clicked, but instead just call the `hi` function:

```
function hi(id, file){
$(id).attr("src", file);
}
```

This is supposed to enlarge the image (by swapping first_img.jpg to second_img.jpg.)
What can I do if I want to swap it back again? As in, click on the swapped image (second_img.jpg) and have it changed back to first_img.jpg; a reversal of what the `hi` function does.

Comment: Are you first_img and second_img named in similar way? like 'image1_small' and 'image1_large' for example?

Comment: No, they're not. In fact, they're generated with PHP, but I'm just using HTML here to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for not navigating to google.com when clicked, you can just change the `href` to be: `href="#"`.

For the image swap, why not make your `hi` function work both ways, as a toggle? You could do this:

```
<a onclick="swapImage('#i_15', 'first_img.jpg', 'second_img.jpg');" href="#" >
    <img id="i_15" src="first_img.jpg" />
</a>

function swapImage(id, firstImage, secondImage) {
    var imageToLoad = $(id).attr("src") == firstImage ? secondImage : firstImage;

    $(id).attr("src", imageToLoad);
}
```

Comment: I would take this further by passing "this" rather than an ID.

Comment: @Diodeus: `this` would reference the anchor element, but I do agree that changing the argument to something like "element" and passing in `$('#i_15')` (and changing the references appropriately) would probably be better.

Comment: You still have to deal with the page refreshing if you use this code. I think you need to add something to keep that from happening.

Comment: @Alex: Despite fragment identifiers causing history, they do not cause a page reload. See [this article](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/), item number 4. If the OP doesn't want this link to cause history, then he would indeed have to make a change to prevent that.

Comment: Interesting, then what exactly does cause the page to refresh when you click on a link? I need to look into this a bit more. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I simply added `return:false;` after the function, so it doesn't cause any refresh

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your `hi()` function should work.

```
function hi(id, file){
    var $id = $(id);
    if($id.attr("src") == file)
    {
        $id.attr("src", $.data($id, "orig"));
    }
    else
    {
        $.data($id, "orig", $id.attr("src"));
        $id.attr("src", file);
    }
}
```